# How to fit content within card?

Tags: css, flexbox, vuetify.js

**Context:**

I am trying to achieve the below mock in all the screens, such that the content within the v-card is divided into 20% [card-title], 60% [card-text] and 20% [card-actions] and if the content inside the card-title/card-text/card-actions is more it should shrink in. I am trying to achieve this using flexbox. I have tried restructuring layout multiple times make the layout shrink in.

I am using vuetify 1.5.

[image]

**Problem:**
The content overflows the v-card-text,v-card-title and v-card-action,also v-card-text and v-card-action is pushed down and is not visible. I assume the layout structure that I have tried till now is not proper.

[image]

This the structure i have followed

```
  <v-container fluid grid-list-md>
    <v-layout>
      <v-flex>
        <v-container>
          <v-layout>
            <v-flex>
              <v-card>
                <v-card-title>Card header</v-card-title>
                <v-card-text>Card content</v-card-text>
                <v-card-action>Card footer</v-card-action>
              </v-card>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-container>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
```

Kind of stuck right now, any suggestions would be really helpful.
This is what I have tried till now.

https://codepen.io/adatdeltax/pen/RwKyRqE

Comment: May I know the reason why you have hardcoded the height in v-card as :height="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown?'306px':'346px'", this is causing the issue, can you please share the expectation and card behaviour in terms of height